# Does ExecutorService consume thread capacity

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, oop, executorservice

I am trying to create a messaging application. I have a class called `MessageServer` and I intend to connect clients to this class. 
Every `Client` class implements `Runnable`. 
My approach is to create an `ExecutorService` inside the `MessageServer` class, and execute every client from here.

My question is, can I execute infinite amount `Runnable`'s depending on the `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(x)` or do they count as individual threads?

I am open to new approaches if possible.
I also start the MessageServer thread from main method.

**MessageServer**

```
public class MessageServer extends Server implements Runnable{

    static LinkedList<Message> messages = new LinkedList<>();

    LinkedList<Client> clients = new LinkedList<>();

    ExecutorService clientPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public MessageServer() throws IOException {
        super(Vars.MESSAGE_PORT);
    }

    public void addToMessages(Message message) {
        if (!messages.contains(message)) {
            messages.add(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

                //Read Client data then add to the list
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream in =  new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

                Client current = (Client)in.readObject();
                clients.add(current);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MessageServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

*Super class* **Server**

```
public class Server{
    InetAddress address;

    LinkedList<Client> clients = new LinkedList<>();

    protected ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(Vars.SERVER_TIMEOUT_MS);

        //ip = Utilities.getIp();

        address = serverSocket.getInetAddress();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client implements Serializable {

protected String nickname;
protected long id;
protected int key;

// MessageServer
protected transient ObjectOutputStream msgOut;
protected transient ObjectInputStream msgIn;
protected transient Socket messageSocket;

protected transient Socket videoSocket;


public Client(String nickname){
    this.nickname = nickname;
    createid();
    makeConnection();
    key = (int) (Math.random() * 8999) + 1000;
}

void makeConnection(){
    try {
        messageSocket = new Socket(Vars.IP, Vars.MESSAGE_PORT);
        //TODO make connection with videoServer
        msgOut = new ObjectOutputStream(messageSocket.getOutputStream());
        msgIn = new ObjectInputStream(messageSocket.getInputStream());

        msgOut.writeObject(this);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

final void createid(){
    id = 3;
    id = 13 * id + Objects.hashCode(this.nickname);
}

// Getters-setters-hashcode-equals
```

Comment: Just in case the answers below don't make this absolutely clear: A `Runnable` is _not_ a thread. A `Runnable` is just an ordinary object with a method named `run()`. An `ExecutorService` is an ordinary object that promises to _eventually_ call the `run()` method of each `Runnable` object that you `submit()` to it. In most cases, those calls will happen in private _worker threads_ that are created and managed by the `ExecutorService` object.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, can I execute infinite amount Runnable's depending on the Executors.newFixedThreadPool(x) or do they count as individual threads?

You can add far more runnables than threads. They are stored in a queue, and executed when a thread is available.

In the Javadoc of the [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-):

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.

So, yes, it's "infinite".

Comment: So I can add as many as, say 100 client runnables to my messageserver executor?

Comment: @guacamolest yes.

Comment: Lol, we have basically answered the same thing at the same moment.

Comment: Okay i think i figured, cached is basically like a List, unbounded.

Comment: @guacamolest You need to understand that there is not a 1 to 1 relation between threads and `Runnable`s in a thread pool. When the size is fixed, lets say 10, out of 20 `Runnable`s only 10 are going ot be executed. The other ones are queued until one of the core pool threads has finished its assigned `Runnable`. If you want all clients to run at a time, you need to use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, which will create a thread for each `Runnable` directly.

Comment: @akuzminykh "Lol, we have basically answered the same thing at the same moment." somebody forgot the synchronized block.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, can I execute infinite amount `Runnable`s depending on the `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(x)` or do they count as individual threads?

The thread pool with fixed size has internally a queue where tasks are queued. Each `Runnable` is put into that queue. A thread takes a new task from the queue if it has finished its current task.

There is no limit of tasks you can queue, except hardware limits. When you queue e.g. 20 tasks and have 10 threads in the pool, only 10 of those tasks, or rather `Runnable`s, are executed. In your case, only `x` clients would be running because there are only `x` threads in the pool with fixed size.

You should use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` in your case. This thread pool doesn't have a limited size, which enables the pool to run all clients at the same time.